# JAVA_HOME pointing to JRE not JDK

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am currently installing Maven for Spring boot.
After I installed the Maven and set the system variables and path, I encounter
"JAVA_HOME should point to JDK not a JRE"

What is the problem here?

Comment: I went through one by one, but none of them useful in my case

Comment: Ok, can you please describe your situation a bit better then? What is the value of `JAVA_HOME`? What operating system are you running? Can you tell us *anything* besides the error you're receiving?

Comment: I solved the problem from another post
One mentioned to echo %PROGRAMFILES%
Because maven doesnt check space. so its default is automatically pointing to JRE